# Understanding the microsoft.storage.blobcreated event

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use an event trigger to load data from Azure blob to a SQL DB.

What I want to understand is when does the event **Microsoft.storage.blobcreated** actually get triggered, in the case when I'm creating large files in Azure blob storage?

1. Is it when my file was just created and which is still loading data or
2. When the file has finished loading all the data

In the first case, the copy activity may lose out on some data as the file hasn't yet completely downloaded all the data.

Also, while we're at it, is there a way we can handle any modifications to an existing blob so that the modified file also gets downloaded to my SQL DB?

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer, thank you !

Comment: @LeonYue: Thanks for the response. This has cleared my doubts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when your file is created finished in Azure blob storage, you will have the blob properties, such as URL、TYPE and SIZE:
[image]

The **Microsoft.storage.blobcreated** event need these blob properties as event properties, You can get this from the blob created event example:

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xstoretestaccount",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/testcontainer/blobs/testfile.txt",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-06-26T18:41:00.9584103Z",
  "id": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e069631",
  "data": {
    "api": "PutBlockList",
    "clientRequestId": "6d79dbfb-0e37-4fc4-981f-442c9ca65760",
    "requestId": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e000000",
    "eTag": "0x8D4BCC2E4835CD0",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "contentLength": 524288,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://example.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/testfile.txt",
    "sequencer": "00000000000004420000000000028963",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

For more details, please see: [Event properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage#event-properties).

It means that you data will not be loaded to you SQL database until the file created finished.

For your another question,  is there a way we can handle any modifications to an existing blob so that the modified file also gets downloaded to my SQL DB?

Yes, there is. For example， you can using Logic app with the trigger: **[Azure Blob Storage - When a blob is added or modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/#triggers)**. You can reference this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-trigger).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a follow up question: So, if I take down my sink(SQL DB) after the event was created, will the pipeline still run? If no, then once my sink is up and running, will the data factory pick up the events from when the pipelines started failing?

Comment: Thank, ironMan.  I haven't try it,  so I can't give you a positive answer. If you have more ideas, just try it. Show us the error, we will help you. Thanks again for accept my  answer, have a good day.